# Uniqueness of isomorphism to linear spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

> Even if an isomorphism between two linear spaces $L$ and $M$ over a field $\mathbb{K}$ exists, it is defined uniquely only in two cases:
>
> 1. $L=M=\{0\}$ and
> 2. $L$ and $M$ are one-dimensional, while $\mathbb{K}$ is a field consisting of two elements.

How can I show this fact? Does anyone have any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $2$-dimensions and above there are more than one isomorphism because you can map basis elements to basis elements and there are more than one way to do that.

For $1$-dimensional spaces, there is a map from the non-zero elements of the field to the set of automorphisms of any one-dimensional spaces induced by multiplication.  Precomposing any isomorphism with an automorphism will change the isomorphism.  So, if the field has more than two elements you can get different isomorphisms.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

1. is extreamly easy. Recall that if $f,g:L\to M$ then $f=g$ if and only if $\forall v\in L,\,f(v)=g(v)$, so you can prove it only with set theory (an isomorphism is a bijection).
2. I guess you know that if $f\in\mathcal{L}(L,M)$ and $L$ is finite dimensional then $f$ is totally defined only by knowing the images of a basis of $L$, right? So you can use this.